# Is the order of model ID's a reliable indication of the order the models were created in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## The Scenario

**Update**: It was brought to my attention that ordering by `created_at` will actually compare a millisecond float that's of sufficient resolution (by far). However, while I feel a bit dumb now, my question still stands. My scenario is just irrelevant, so I removed it.

## The Question

I know that the database knows precisely the order of creation by tracking a row's ID.

**Are there any pitfalls in relying on latest ID to determine order?**

Comment: I'm not sure that the question can be accurately answered as it currently stands, because the id is generated in different ways in each database. For example: We use MongoDB a lot and it generates unique, but non-sequential ids. MySQL has autoincrement functionality but in PostgreSQL you must create a sequence, which could incorporate a number of variables. Then you have the problem of manual insertions...

Comment: That makes sense. Since your answer led to me actually solving the underlying issue, I see that the question I posed is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is to replace the latest_post_at with something more precise than a second. `Time.now.to_f` instead of `.to_i` will give you sub-second precision (millisecond I think, the docs aren't clear). Should two posts happen to have the same millisecond timestamp you could use the id as a tie-breaker.

Comment: Oh, duh. `created_at` already contains millisecond data. In fact, I now see that the Post model code that updated the parent Topic's `latest_post_at` cache had a bug that was could set the latest_post_at to the deleted post (still in memory). I guess my original question still stands, but now my demo scenario is inaccurate unless it's possible to create two posts with identical `created_at.to_f`.

Comment: Furthermore, considering that `3.times { puts Time.now.to_f }` produces unique values (although identical up to the 6th decimal), I think I'm pretty safe from the event that database I/O + Rails can produce anything less unique!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using whatever is the "natural" way of generating autoincrementing surrogate primary keys for your database, the only pitfall that comes to mind is that the order in which the database sequencer generated the IDs might not be the order in which the transactions that create the `Post` records start or finish. (Or however you define the time when a post is "created".)

Considering the transaction should normally take a fraction of a second to complete this uncertainty might be irrelevant for your needs.